# How to properly decorate a function to be overridden in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-decorators

I'd like to designate some of my baseclass functions for override. (The override should not be necessarily enforced.) What is the proper way of doing this?

I mean sth like

```
class Base(object):
    ...
    @abstractmethod
    def fun(self):
        pass

class Derived(Base):

    @override
    def fun(self):
        pass
```

EDIT:

I want my code to raise an UnimplementedException if the function is not overridden.

Comment: What do you mean with this: _The override should not be necessarily enforced._ What do you want to if not overridden?

Comment: If you don't want to have to override a method, you should not declare it abstract and provide a basic (even empty) implementation...

Comment: Thanks for the questions, updated the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Base(object):
    ...
    def fun(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Source: http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods